# Weird strstr behaviour

Tags: c, strstr

i'm trying to find the position of substring in a string.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void find_str(char const* str, char const* substr) 
{
    char* pos = strstr(str, substr);
    if(pos) {
        printf("found the string '%s' in '%s' at position: %d\n", substr, str, pos - str);
    } else {
        printf("the string '%s' was not found in '%s'\n", substr, str);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    char* str = "gdeasegrfdtyguhıjohhıhugfydsasdrfgthyjkjhghh";
    find_str(str, "hh");
    find_str("dhenhheme    kekekeke hhtttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttthhtttttttttttt", "hh");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> found the string 'hh' in
>   'gdeasegrfdtyguhıjohhıhugfydsasdrfgthyjkjhghh' at position: 19
>
> found
>   the string 'hh' in 'dhenhheme    kekekeke
>   hhtttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttthhtttttttttttt' at position:
>   4

In first example it says its in the position 19. But shouldn't it say 18? Because in the second example it says 4. And it starts at the beginning of substring.

I'm confused.

Comment: `strstr()` counts bytes, not graphemes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The character `'ı'` is not an ASCII character, so it probably takes up two bytes.

Comment: Actually, it still may be a single byte, depending on the OP's local code page settings (or his editor's). But then this problem would not be there (then again, there *would* be other problems).